# Parameters routes are not redirects to page 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I ask them to help solve this problem, follows the code :

Controller

```
   angular.module('tareasApp')
  .controller('HumorCtrl', function ($scope, $route, $location) { 

    $scope.pageName = $route.current.params.pageName;

$scope.items =[
 {    
      href:'/humor/smile-today', 
      img:'smile.jpg', 
      descricao:'Those Relaxing Sounds of Waves'
 }
];
 });

  angular.module('tareasApp')
  .controller('NewsCtrl', function ($scope, $route, $location) { 

    $scope.pageName = $route.current.params.pageName;

$scope.items =[
 {    
      href:'/news/news-today', 
      img:'news.jpg', 
      descricao:'Those Relaxing Sounds of Waves'
 }
];
 });
```

App.js

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        title: 'Home Page',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
       })
      .when('/humor/:pageName', {
        templateUrl: 'views/wizard.html',
        controller: 'HumorCtrl'
      })
      .when('/news/:pageName', {
          templateUrl: 'views/wizard.html',
          controller: 'NewsCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

When I type any route that does not exist right after the bar, eg:

> domain.com/hhhoedr

returns to the start page .

The problem is in the sub-directory, which contains the `$routeParams`, typing a page that does not exist , eg:

> domain.com/humor/hhhoedr

is not redirecting to index.html or to 404.html.

I would like to adapt this code, [I found in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862225/page-doesnt-redirect-to-the-specified-page-on-invalid-url), to my app.

```
  myApp.constant('EXISTING_PAGES', [
    'page1',
    'page2',
    ...
]);

  resolve: {
                exists: function ($location, $route) {

                    if (EXISTING_PAGES.indexOf($route.current.params.page) === -1) {

                        $location.path('/error/404');
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }


        .when('/error/404', {
            templateUrl: '404.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/error/404'
        });
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you are typing any route `e.g-domain.com/hhhoedr`,It is returning to starting page because check you last part of your code,you are setting it like below.

```
.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
```

If you will set anything except from your all `.when` part it will simple redirect to the starting page.Try to set it for redirecting to any other page as per your requirement.

Ok,Now you can write it like below.

```
.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/here give your destination path(e.g-404.html...etc)'
      });
```

Comment: Edited my question ... you know how I can adjust this code,  [I found in another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862225/page-doesnt-redirect-to-the-specified-page-on-invalid-url), to my code ?

Comment: When using $routeParams is not that simple. Needless to say the $routrParams when there is some error in the URL.